# Testing Lyapunov's Central Limit Theorem by Simulation

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Lyapunov's CLT states that the sum of $n$ independent (not necessarily i.i.d.) random variables converges to the normal distribution if the Laypunov's CLT condition is satisfied. I used simulation to verify this theorem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import normaltest, gamma

s = np.zeros(1000)
a = np.random.uniform(size = 10000)
for i in range(1000):
    x = gamma.rvs(a,loc = 0)
    s[i] = np.sum(x)/100

k2, p = normaltest(s)
```

But when I test samples s for Gaussianity I get p-values around 0.25. I also tried verifying the classical CLT for i.i.d. random variables by setting a = 5 for all variables and got a p-value around $10^{-285}$.

What is the reason for seeing such a result for Lyapunov's case? Is it because the Lyapunov's condition is not satisfied or is it because Lyapunov's CLT converges much slower?

Comment: There is an error in your code: size = 10000 should be size = 1000 (it is not essential, of course). Anyway, I ran your code several times, and got all $p$-values larger than $0.1$. So everything is ok, the problem might be with your Python installation. Update (or reinstall) everything and rerun.

Comment: @zhoraster I wondered about that too. An alternative is that the OP is drawing 1000 samples of x, each of size 10000. Then the mean should be calculated as a division by 10000.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong, 1000 or 10000 does not matter. Anyway, I get normal $p$-values.

Comment: I also ran the code a number of times and got $p$-values larger than 0.1 (on 8 out of 10 tries) -- I concur with @zhoraster

Comment: Suggestion: If you're going to post your code, use random.seed() to set the random number seed at the start.  That way, other people can replicate your results exactly.